# undefined columns error in R

Tags: r, statistics

Here is my simple R code. I want to only keep values which are smaller than 1.

Does anyone have any good ideas? Thanks.

```
df <- read.csv('~/Downloads/foo.tsv', sep='\t', header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- c('foo')
df$foo <- as.numeric(df$foo)

goodValue <- df[df$foo <= 1]
```

The last line has the following error:

> `Error in`[.data.frame`(df, df$foo <= 1) : undefined columns
>   selected`

Comment: Could you give us a look at your data, and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
goodValue <- df[df$foo <= 1,] # if you want all columns
goodValue <- df$foo[df$foo <= 1] # if you only want foo (if you had multiple columns)
```

Comment: Thanks Hack-R, vote up and wondering why need additional `,`? My data `df` has only one column.

Comment: @LinMa You're welcome. It's just the syntax in data.frame for referencing columns.  If you only have 1 column you don't really need to use a data.frame class, so when they wrote the syntax of that class they didn't make it check the number of columns it has before evaluating the index reference.

Comment: Thanks Hack-R for correct my understanding, have a good weekend. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[foo <= 1]
```

Or with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(foo <= 1)
```